# ItemsControl/ListBox items exceed available width

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, listboxitem

I want text in column 3 wrap and have no horizontal scrollbar. Why doesn't this work?

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="listMessages" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Column1"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Column2"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="Column3"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Column4"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Text1" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Text2" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Very long text that should wrap to the next line, but it doesn't work" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Text4" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Items take more width than is available to ItemsControl. Same problem is with ListBox.

I tried to add `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollbarVisibility=Disabled` both on ItemsControl and Grid, but this doesn't help.

Comment: Try to remove the SharedSizeGroup attribute from the <ColumnDefinition /> element.

Comment: Or do what you usually do to show columns in an ItemsControl: use a ListView with a GridView.

Comment: Removing SharedSizeGroup does not change anything. I use ItemsControl because I don't need selection.

Comment: My mistake, SharedSizeGroup does make it wrap. But then, I do need SharedSizeGroup to have all columns with same width. How to solve this?

Comment: Use a fixed MaxWidth or MinWidth. You can't both wrap and have a SharedSizeGroup.

Comment: I got this now. I was removing IsSharedSizeScope instead of SharedSizeGroup before. Removing SharedSizeGroup for third column does the trick, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text will be wrapped if you don't set the `SharedSizeGroup` property:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
```

Text wrapping and shared size groups don't go well together. You may want to specify a fixed `MaxWidth` for the `ColumnDefinition` or the `TextBlock`.